# Saving file to phone instead of SD card

Tags: android, file, save

In my app I save an XML file to the user's SD card by doing `File newxmlfile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Message.xml");`

But not all users have SD-cards in their phone and therefore my app is likely to crash.

How must I change my File creating method in order to save the file to the phone's memory instead of the SD-card?

Also, how must I change the loading of the file? (currently: `new InputSource(new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Message.xml"))`)

EDIT: I don't think you got the question right. I know the Data-Storage page of the Android Docs and I've read it. I just want to know how I should it adjust it to match my current way of saving and loading a file.

Comment: Every Android-compatible device supports a shared "external storage" that you can use to save files. This can be a removable storage media(such as an SD card) or an internal(non-removable) storage. Note: don't be confused by the word "external" here. This directory can better be thought as media/shared storage. It is a filesystem that is shared across all applications(does not enforce permissions).Traditionally this is an SD card, but it may also be implemented as built-in storage in a device that is distinct from the protected internal storage and can be mounted as a filesystem on a computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it by changing

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Message.xml"
```

into

```
Environment.getDataDirectory() + "/data/com.companyname.appname/files/Message.xml"
```

Answer (score 3):

First you should check if External Storage (SD card) is available and ready to write to by checking getExternalStorageState().
Read more here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

Then if SD card not available you can write to internal storage.
Read more here for example on how to write and read: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Comment: The thing is that I don't want my app to get fragmented. I want 1 version that works the same on all devices. Plus I don't want to have checks all over my app. This is much easier.

Comment: Ok, then you should only save to internal storage, as you wrote in the question, and not even check external storage.

Answer (score 2):

Try andriods [Data-Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`openFileOutput`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) to get an access to the internal storage. For more info, you should read the [documentation on internal storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal).