# Creating a textfile and saving it to a particular location in android phone

Tags: android, file, copying

I want to create a text file of the data received from bluetooth and then save it to a location from where it can be used by another application.

How can I solve this using code?

Comment: Please post what you have done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like dupe/related to [StackOverflow: Saving file to phone in stead of SD-card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678544/saving-file-to-phone-in-stead-of-sd-card)

You should be able to use regular java File IO classes to save the actual data to the file.

Answer (score 3):

Using `FileWriter` is one of the easiest ways:

```
File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(new File(dir, "name.txt"));
writer.append("Hola\n");
writer.append("Hello\n");
writer.append("Etc...\n");
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

This will save the file to the SDCard directory, which is accessible by other applications. Make sure to include the [`WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) permission to your Manifest file.

Comment: i don't want to copy to sdcard directory but to some other directory in phone memory accessible by other applications

Comment: There's no other directory accessible for other applications ;)

Comment: i want to copy the file to dropbox folder then what should be the code.

Comment: Yes, you can create another directory but inside the SDCard. There are lots of tutorials of how to do so :)