# CSV file output for use on PC

Tags: android, gps, save, storage

First off I am no master developer.

We have a GPS application that creates gps tracks in an SQLite database.

The way the app works now:

- The user asks in the application for a file export
- CSV files are created for each track on the SD card
- The user then connects the device with a USB cable to a windows machine and   copies the files to a network location
- A python job loads the tracks into an oracle SDE database

The problem - we keep getting corrupted SD cards so their is a push to remove the SD card dependency

The question - can we output the csv files to a dir on the device's internal files system. Such as the downloaded folder?

We are on Samsung 10.1 Tab 4's running KitKat and Lollipop. However, we will need to deploy more tabs soon. They will most likely have Marshmallow on them.

Comment: You can find a quite straight forward description on how to do this in the documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save CSV file in internal storage with flag `MODE_WORLD_READABLE`, but remember that

> As of N attempting to use this mode will throw a SecurityException.

Here is a [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_READABLE)

---

Here is an example how [Save a File on Internal Storage](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html):

```
String filename = "myfile";
String string = "Hello world!";
FileOutputStream outputStream;

try {
  outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
  outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
  outputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: or look to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678544/saving-file-to-phone-instead-of-sd-card

Comment: Okay, thanks! That looks like a great solution for now. But if and when we need to support Android N this will no longer work...